# Is Pycharm not accepting ">>>" in docstrings intended?

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings, special-characters, docstring

Here is what happens when I try to use ">>>" at the beginning of a line in a docstring in Pycharm (version 2023.2.5).

[image]

It gives me an unresolved reference warning.

---

It works fine if the >>> doesn't start the line:

[image]

It also works as long as there's less than 3 in a row:

[image]

Is this behavior intentional? If so, what's the reason?

Comment: doctests are treated and checked as if they were actual code (and executed as part of the test suit if set-up correctly) so every name is expected to be defined on a previous line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @DeepSpace.